# When I turn on my VPN, I lose internet connection

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, openvpn

When I trun on my VPN (I use openvpn) either through terminal or through settings->network I loose connection to the internet. I tried ticking off the box that says use for resources on this network only it worked but my ip address stayed the same. When I tried the same configuration file on a different computer it worked just fine. The one it's not working on is ubuntu 20.04 the one it is working on is kubuntu 20.04. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by moving file /etc/systemd/system/openvpn-iptables.service .
Note that this will probably not help you. This was only a problem because I was experimenting and accidentally created that file, but it still is worth checking for it.